# extract text from pdf in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extensions. What i want to realize is that the popup can display the text from pdf. I have searched the PDF.js and write the following code in backgroud.js of chrome extensions to test:

```
‘use strict’;
var pdf = PDFJS.getDocument('http://www.pacer.gov/documents/pacermanual.pdf');


    var pdf = PDFJS.getDocument('pacermanual.pdf');
    pdf.then(function(pdf) {
     var maxPages = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;
     for (var j = 1; j <= maxPages; j++) {
        var page = pdf.getPage(j);

        // the callback function - we create one per page
        var processPageText = function processPageText(pageIndex) {
          return function(pageData, content) {
            return function(text) {
              // bidiTexts has a property identifying whether this
              // text is left-to-right or right-to-left
              for (var i = 0; i < text.bidiTexts.length; i++) {
                str += text.bidiTexts[i].str;
              }

              if (pageData.pageInfo.pageIndex === 
                  maxPages - 1) {
                // later this will insert into an index
                console.log(str);
              }
            }
          }
        }(j);

        var processPage = function processPage(pageData) {
          var content = pageData.getTextContent();

          content.then(processPageText(pageData, content));
        }

        page.then(processPage);
     }
    });
```

The manifest is shown as follow:

```
{
    "name": "englishhelper",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ],
    "background":{
       "script":["background.js","PDF.js"]
    },
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"icon_png",
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

The popup.html is shown as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="background.js"></script>
<script src="PDF.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The console shows that "PDFJS is not defined". The "PDF.js" has been included in popup.html. Is it possible that chrome extension use PDF.js?

Comment: Your code is in the background page, yet the library is not included there. What do you expect?

Comment: I am sorry i did not explain clearly. The "PDF.js" has been downloaded and add in popup.html like <script src="PDF.js"></script> @Xan

Comment: Is `background.js`, despite the name, executing also in the popup? If not, they are two separate contexts. All in all, please include your manifest to the question.

Comment: @Xan Thank you for your several times reply.The manifest and popup has been shown above

Comment: What's inside the `PDF.js` file? The API looks like the PDF.js library from Mozilla, but the error in the console suggests that you did not correctly include pdf.js.

Comment: Yes, "PDF.js"is the library from Mozilla, i thought i have included "PDF.js"as shown above. As mentioned by Xan, i changed the order but it still doesn't work. Is there any better way to include "PDF.js" and call the function? @Rob W

Comment: @jiezhang Did you reload the extension (at `chrome://extensions`) after modifying the manifest file?

Comment: of course i reload the extension. In console of popup, it shows "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". Do you know any success case of extension use "PDF.js"?

Comment: @jiezhang Yes. In fact, I'm the author of the [PDF.js extension that is used by over a half million users](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm). Assuming that your code does not work after swapping the order of the `<script>` tags, I believe that you did not put the right content in your "PDF.js" file. Could you show its content (e.g. by pasting its content on http://pastebin.com)?

Comment: What i want to realize is to display pdf content in popup of chrome extension. Is there any effective way? Many thx @RobW

Comment: The "PDF.js" i used in here:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hubgit/hubgit.github.com/master/2011/11/pdftotext/pdf.js. Should i download whole file not just "PDF.js" @RobW

Comment: @jiezhang That file contains the `PDFJS` object. I think that you did *not* swap the `<script>` tags in your `popup.html`. To fix the error, reverse the order of the `<script>` tags. Your choice for file naming makes me believe that you do not understand the Chrome extension architecture at all, start reading here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted. To get back to your original issue:

Comment: Sorry, one more question. I have solute this problem used function getPdf and PDFDoc in"PDF.js". I have got the constructor of PDF. Can you tell me how to get the text content? Which function should i use？@RobW

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong load order.** *(Do we have a canonical question for that?)*

`background.script` or `content_scripts[i].js` key in the manifest is an array, in other words an ordered list.

Scripts are loaded and executed in the sequence defined there; you need to make sure libraries are loaded before they are used.

In your case, you need to swap them around:

```
"background":{
   "script": ["PDF.js", "background.js"]
},
```

Same applies to the order of `<script>` tags in HTML, for instance in your `popup.html`

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work after changing the order.

Comment: It would be a separate problem though.